# How to create a views display that is not a block or a page?

Tags: views

I often use `views_embed_view()` in various places. I find myself creating views with multiple displays, each with slightly overridden settings for different purposes. I end up creating a lot of "Block" displays just because I need multiple displays. But I don't actually need it to provide a block, and I don't *want* all of those blocks cluttering up my system.

My question: is there a "generic" display (like Master) that I could use to create multiple displays without resorting to "block" or "page" displays?

Comment: Could you use Attachments maybe?

Comment: Thanks Clive! I think attachments are exactly it. I just get hung up on thinking of them as "attachments," which is why I asked you all ...

Comment: I now use the 'embed' display type for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can create Attachments for the view.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try View Field View module. It provide the option to embed a view inside another view.